# local path displaying when I click hyperlink to different website

Tags: javascript, html, href

```
fetch(www.gnewsapi.com/news/someID).then(response =>
newsurl.href = JSON.stringify(data.articles[0].url)
fetch('https://gnews.io/api/v3/search?q=platformer&token=642h462loljk').then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(data => {
    newstitle.textContent = JSON.stringify(data.articles[0].title),
    newsdetails.textContent = JSON.stringify(data.articles[0].description),
    **newsurl.href = JSON.stringify(data.articles[0].url)**
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" id="news-img" src="" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title" id="news-title">News</h5>
          <p class="card-text" id="news-details">Download it</p>
          <a id="news-url" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I click the hyperlink button it opens User/Me/Documents"https://www.androidpolice.com" I want it to open just the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the URL (which is a string) through `JSON.stringify` which turns it into a JSON representation of a string (by adding `"` around it).

Since the URL now starts with a `"` it is a relative URL.

Don't add `"`! Don't use `JSON.stringify`!